# Does C++ have automatic access to all the available memory in the machine

Tags: c++, memory

I am coming from a GC VM environment (Clojure) where the amount of memory available to an application is whatever the JVM started up with, which is always much less (usually) than the actual memory available on the machine.

I am wondering if, as a system programming language, C++ just automatically has access to all the GB of RAM on a system?

I understand that the stack memory area is going to be limited, but what about the heap?

For example, consider the odd scenario of wanting a list of doubles that is a few hundred million long. Some seemingly excessive memory allocation like this:

`auto pvec=new std::vector<double>(125000000);`

This is approximately 1 GB of memory if each `double` is 8 bytes. On a machine with 16 GB of RAM, is this a non-problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if, as a system programming language, C++ just automatically has access to all the GB of RAM on a system?

That is not a question of programming language, but of memory protection.

On modern computers, CPUs together with the operating system implement so-called virtual memory, which is an address range of the process you're running. Into that address range, physical RAM can get mapped, and normally is mapped only in small chunks. A normal program never has the chance to access memory that doesn't belong to its own process' memory mapping, and a virtual memory address says nothing about the physical RAM mapped to it.

If you're, however, using C++ or any other language to code on bare metal without memory protection, then your program would have access to all the RAM; notice this is never the case for what you'd consider a "normal" program (I can tell you're not a microcontroller or OS developer).